# Creating MySQL database for storing imported KML?

Tags: kml, mysql

I need to create a MySQL database for storing coordinates from a KML file with the
structure as follows:

```
<Placemark>
        <name>someplace</name>
        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <Polygon>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        73.13693971060766,19.25310233594502,0 73.13693833446244,19.25310233595927,0 73.13693403840304,19.2530984545477,0 73.13693244215831,19.25309329030865,0 73.13693090444444,19.25308942538022,0 73.13692794507664,19.25308428308517,0 73.13692494004152,19.25307787269911,0 73.13692467634385,19.25307148170985,0 73.1369258304161,19.25306638278946,0 73.13692698179315,19.2530612962149,0 73.1369322686994,19.25305748929283,0 73.13693618566978,19.25305368927265,0 73.13694020972429,19.25305242409976,0 73.1369455322031,19.25304989609698,0 73.13695090854537,19.25304863322264,0 73.13695628164153,19.25304737111269,0 73.13696294560927,19.25304484915161,0 73.13696837570761,19.25304484914826,0 73.13697652081103,19.2530448491438,0 73.13698202045055,19.25304610973631,0 73.13698895342023,19.2530486332095,0 73.13699582091516,19.25304989604919,0 73.13700004851012,19.25305242405945,0 73.13700428114488,19.25305495514516,0 73.137008596689,19.25305875746043,0 73.13701292005057,19.25306256664898,0 73.13701733179597,19.25306765632393,0 73.1370191023439,19.25307403574487,0 73.13702208277293,19.25307787264039,0 73.13702249452535,19.25308428301952,0 73.1370229075506,19.25309071284612,0 73.13702323885482,19.25309587081664,0 73.13702227801461,19.25310233591246,0 73.13702260952107,19.25310752220441,0 73.1370201827993,19.25311272114856,0 73.1370177501589,19.2531179327989,0 73.13701531155583,19.25312315721282,0 73.1370114025442,19.25312708392549,0 73.13700602252482,19.25312970574124,0 73.1370006359243,19.25313233078209,0 73.13699509258757,19.25313233079353,0 73.13698816344083,19.25313233078499,0 73.13698116356548,19.25313101786714,0 73.13697555292208,19.25312970576528,0 73.13696994578734,19.2531283944655,0 73.13696434201735,19.25312708395525,0 73.13695999711467,19.25312315723566,0 73.13695697863325,19.25311793285053,0 73.13695264975624,19.25311402288048,0 73.13694832879452,19.2531101201258,0 73.13694395681273,19.25310492752692,0 73.13693971060766,19.25310233594502,0 
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>place2</name>
        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <Polygon>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        73.13723765697174,19.25290222725077,0 73.13723989677642,19.25289857411988,0 73.13724050975087,19.25289250009896,0 73.13724140951585,19.2528888642842,0 73.13724216325605,19.25288402638158,0 73.13724690239067,19.2528791999123,0 73.1372491215834,19.25287558746117,0 73.13725413788218,19.25287318265183,0 73.13725944636737,19.25287318265056,0 73.13726740917318,19.25287318261767,0 73.1372740448365,19.25287318261646,0 73.13727818083784,19.25287438462484,0 73.13728161429077,19.25288040541489,0 73.1372835696157,19.25288523471525,0 73.13728286450872,19.25289007539774,0 73.13727964512475,19.25289614231522,0 73.1372761061091,19.25289979111273,0 73.13727389776194,19.25290344626298,0 73.13727065467811,19.25290955268617,0 73.13726828301977,19.25291200031773,0 73.13726337940838,19.25291567720809,0 73.13725846706093,19.25291936058711,0 73.13725324778412,19.25292058984915,0 73.13724877730209,19.25291690427552,0 73.13724550831267,19.25291200035216,0 73.13724224708763,19.25290710800144,0 73.13724152171221,19.25290100884397,0 73.13723765697174,19.25290222725077,0 
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
```

How do I store the above in MySQL database?

I need to store coordinates of polygons.

say FE: in kml file, i have highlighted 2 areas. I may required to calculate area(sq. mt) or distance from point a to point b. add custom placemarks with data generated by database

Comment: Do you intend to store as KML or as points? What are your intentions to do with the data after storage?

Comment: I will receive kml file. i need to store coordinates of polygon.

Comment: say FE: in kml file, i have highlighted 2 areas. I may required to calculate area(sq. mt) or distance from point a to point b. add custom placemarks with data generated by database.

Answer (score 2):

I found a blog posting entitled [KML / KMZ data import into MySQL for use with GIS functions](http://web.archive.org/web/20190727075138/http://blog.thecodingfrog.com:80/2009/09/kml-kmz-import-into-mysql-for-use-with.html) by Romain which looks like it will do much of what you are asking.

> For demonstration purposes, the KML polygons will be inserted into a
>   simple table storing a string and a matching polygon definition.

---

The original link above disappeared and has been replaced by one from the Wayback Machine.  I am also copying the relevant content from that post here now:

> For demonstration purposes, the KML polygons will be inserted into a
>   simple table storing a string and a matching polygon definition. Here
>   is the table definition:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `tbl_demo_polygons` (
>                        `polygon_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>                        `name` TEXT NOT NULL,
>                        `polygon` POLYGON NOT NULL,
>                        PRIMARY KEY  (`polygon_id`),
>                        SPATIAL KEY `poly_spx` (`polygon`)
>                      ) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
> ```
>
> The strategy I adopted for this demo is to use a ruby script to
>   generate some SQL INSERT statements which you may then use whichever
>   way suits you.
>
> Without further delay, here is the script: require "rexml/document"
>
> ```
> # we open the file as an XML document
> doc = Document.new File.new("datasource.kml")
>
> # we get all placemark elements as an array.
> all_pms = doc.elements.to_a("//Placemark")
>
> # we create our SQL file will all the insert statements
> f = File.open "dump.sql", "w+"
>
> # we iterate over each Placemark element
> all_pms.each do |pm|
>  # in my demo, the name of the polygon come from the child element name
>  pc_name = pm.elements['name'].text
>
>  # the polygon points come in 1 string by the format is not really MySQL
>  raw_polygon = pm.elements['MultiGeometry/Polygon/outerBoundaryIs/LinearRing/coordinates'].text
>
>  # we need to remove the 3rd coord of each point as we don't need a z-axis in our demo
>  # we do a bit of formatting to please Mr MySQL
>  pc_polygon =  raw_polygon.strip.gsub(',0','#').gsub(',',' ').gsub('#',',').strip[0..-2].split(',').collect!{|p|p.split.reverse!.join(' ')}.join(', ')
>
>  # we concat all this nicely in 1 executable INSERT statement
>  f << "INSERT INTO tbl_demo_polygons (name, polygon) VALUES ('#{pc_name}',PolygonFromText('Polygon((#{pc_polygon}))'));\n"
> end
>
> # we close our stream
> f.flush
> f.close
>
> # happy days!
> ```
>
> This should normally yield a SQL file that move all these polygons
>   into proper MySQL POLYGON geospatial type.

Comment: My apologies for rejecting a suggested edit that replaced a broken URL with its Wayback Machine equivalent.  That URL did not work when I first tested it but a few minutes later it did.  I cannot undo the Decline but I'm inserting the Wayback Machine URL now.  Thank you for providing it.